# Replace nth match of matches with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to find a way to replace nth match of more matches lite this.

```
string = "one two three one one"
```

**How do I target the second occurence of "one"?**

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
string.replace(/\bone\b/gi{2}, "(one)")
```

to get something like this

```
"one two three (one) one"
```

I've done a jsfiddle which is working but it doesn't feel right. Heaps of code and confusing for a simple thing.

https://jsfiddle.net/Rickii/7u7pLqfd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update :

To make it dynamic use this:

```
((?:.*?one.*?){1}.*?)one
```

where the value 1 means (n-1); which in your case is n=2

and replace by:

```
$1\(one\)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/4)

```js
const regex = /((?:.*?one.*?){1}.*?)one/m;
const str = `one two three one one asdfasdf one asdfasdf sdf one`;
const subst = `$1\(one\)`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log( result);
```

Comment: Hey, this works too `((?:.*?one.*?){1})one` I just removed **.*?** after {1} from your solution, can you please tell me if it's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A more general approach would be to use the replacer function.

```js
// Replace the n-th occurrence of "re" in "input" using "transform"
function replaceNth(input, re, n, transform) {
  let count = 0;

  return input.replace(
    re, 
    match => n(++count) ? transform(match) : match);
}

console.log(replaceNth(
  "one two three one one", 
  /\bone\b/gi,
  count => count ===2,
  str => `(${str})`
));

// Capitalize even-numbered words.
console.log(replaceNth(
  "Now is the time",
  /\w+/g,
  count => !(count % 2),
  str => str.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: Thanx for that. It's a great alternative solution to Rizwan M.Tumans. I'll investigate which approach that suits me best.